# asp.net mvc application session variables are null in IIS 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6, session-variables

Everything is working fine locally but then when I deploy the application to IIS 6 server all session variables are null.

In the application I am using the session variables, for example, like so:

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["test"] = "test123";`

`var test = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["test"];`

In my web.config I have the element:
`<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" />`

In the application configuration options in IIS the "Enable session state" option is checked and session timeout set to 20 mins.

Does anyone know how I can enable session for this application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best explanation I can come up with is:

1. Somewhere in your code there's a `Session.Abandon()` or `Session.Clear()`
2. There's an fairly severe exception being thrown in you application that is killing the App Domain and taking out the session with it. Check your Windows event logs (Application and System) to see if there's any unhandled worker process or ASP.NET exceptions being thrown.
3. Your app's application pool settings have been tinkered with perhaps cause the pool to recycle sooner than expected.
4. You have a load balancer or some kind of proxy in front of the server that's mangling your session cookie. Or, if your setup is a load balanced environment sticky sessions aren't configured on your load balancer.

Try using an out of process session manager such as the SQL State manager:

> [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581

Comment: There is no `Session.Abandon()` or `Session.Clear()` and no signs of an exception. I can't see anything out of the ordinary with the app pool and no load balancer. This is so frustrating!!!! Any ideas????

Comment: @MightyAtom - Did you try the out of process SQL session manager? Also watch the site in Fiddler or Chrome dev tools and have a look to see if you're getting an ASP.NET cookie sent and whether it's consistent or changing: `ASP.NET_SessionId`.